# Dominoes falling on each other

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

If i exert a force $\vec{F_1}$ on a domino it would fall onto the second hitting it with a force $\vec{F_2}$, my question is : Would $\vec{||F_2||}$ be equal to $||\vec{F_1}|| + m.a$ or would $\vec{F_1}$ wither away during the fall? Or is my reasoning totally off?

Comment: Not clear. What is $a$ in your question? Is the dot in $m.a$ a scalar product? What exactly is your reasoning here? ie Why do you think $\vec{||F_2||}$ would equal $||\vec{F_1}|| + m.a$? Why would $\vec{||F_1||}$ *wither away* during the fall? I think you have some major misconceptions about how forces work during and after collisions.

Comment: acceleration and no not a dot product. my reasoning was bad i guess, i thought about it again and probably the force 1 is defined with the initial acceleration due to it when the domino first moves.

Comment: See http://www.math.udel.edu/~rossi/Math512/2005/Team3.pdf for an example of theory and experiments.

Answer (score 2):

Dominos typically rotate when they fall, so you should reason in terms of torque and take the angle of the domino on impact into account. So, no, F2 wont be equal to F1 +m.a.

Comment: I've seen the notation before, it means magnitude of vector.

Comment: If you don't know what symbols in a question mean your should not try answering it until you ask the OP (in a comment) or find out on your own.

Comment: cant comment I dont have enough reputation, tried google unsuccessfully too

Comment: couldnt find it here for ex :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_physics_notations

Comment: but anyhow, involving the magnitude makes it even worse, so I'll keep my answer

Comment: For future reference, you have to earn reputation to gain the privilege to comment and until you do earn enough you cannot use an answer instead of commenting - that's against the rules.  And if you try and find something out and can't, that does not mean you can answer anyway (and in effect guess).  That's not how Physics SE works.  Remember this is not a discussion forum, replies are supposed to be proper answers.  People may downvote if they think your answer is incomplete or inaccurate, so it is better for you to only answer what you are certain of.  We all have to do it like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a row of dominoes falling it is clear that the speed of the fall becomes constant. That means that although more and more energy has been released the energy in the falling region is roughly constant. Hence there is a fair bit of dissipation of that energy and the dissapearance of the initial "force" (actually the activation energy)

The exact calculation of forces and torques is not particularly illuminating.